# Showing the JComboBox selected item text only without the Icon?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jcombobox, renderer

I have a `JComboBox` that its renderer is a `JLabel` with an `Icon` for each item in the combo list :

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list,
                Object comboItemObject,
                int comboItemIndex,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
        String comboItemTitle = (String)comboItemObject;
        setText( comboItemTitle );
        setIcon( new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/images/myIcon.png" ) ) );

        return this;
    }
}
```

When i select an item from the comboBox i just want to show the selected item text in the comboBox, and not the item icon also. **Is there a way i can do that ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the rendering code you can check the index. Something like:

```
if (index == -1)
{
    setText(...);
}
else
{
    setText(...);
    setIcon(...);
}
```

Also, you should not be reading the image in the rendering code since code is called frequently.

Comment: its looks like as job for ActionListener, not ItemListener +1

Comment: @camickr: Yes, it works ... Thanks a lot. Just to understand this: When i say (index == -1) it renders the editor of the ComboBox & not the Popup or what ?

Answer (score 1):

then you have to override `isSelected`, and `extends JLabel` is useless, because renderer by defalult returns `JLabel` as Component

Answer (score 0):

To get the text in the `combobox;` a one liner code is all you need.

Create a variable, as I have called mine `Combotext`

then get the `SelectedItem` from the `JComboBox`.

```
 ComboText = jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: 1) Neither `Combotext` nor `ComboText` matches common Java nomenclature.  It should be `comboText`.  2) `JComboBox` can contain `Object`, so if you are after a `String` it is necessary to call `jComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: not an answer to the question (which is about different _rendering_ of the selected item, not about how to get that item)

Comment: some how ended up here, and this was what i was looking for :)